# La locution « dans le cadre de », est-elle l'antonyme de « en marge de » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, antonyme

L'*Académie française* donne les définitions suivantes :

> *Dans le cadre de*, à l’occasion de.

> *En marge de*, à l’écart de, à côté de, en dehors de.

Serait-il correct de conclure, de ce fait, que ces deux locutions sont antonymiques ?

Answer (score 1):

Pas complètement antonymiques puisque dans les deux cas un événement est dépendant d'un autre dans l'espace et dans le temps.

***Dans le cadre*** signifie qu'on reste dans les limites de ce qui est prévu:

> *Dans le cadre des négociations, il a été décidé que...*

***En marge de*** peut signifier *à l'occasion de, mais en dehors de ce qui était programmé*:

> *En marge des négociations, les deux chefs d'état se sont rencontrés en privé...*

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais que *non*. Imaginons une île au milieu de la mer: le terrain est le cadre, la mer est l'opposé du cadre, alors que la plage est la marge. One pourrais dire que la mer est l'opposé du terrain dans cet exemple, mais la plage ne l'est pas - elle est la partie de terrain ou peut même être considere comme *hors de terrain*, mais elle n'est pas la partie de la mer non plus.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu "dans le cadre de" ou "en marge de" utilisé en parlant d'une île ou d'un territoire.

Comment: @XouDo je ne propose pas d'en utiliser literalement pour parler des îles - j'utilise cette analogie pour expliquer les relations logiques. J'ai pu egalement parler en terms des [diagrammes de Venn](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagramme_de_Venn), mais ça serait peut-être trop technique.

Comment: D'accord. C'est juste qu'on entend la plupart de temps "en marge de"/"dans le cadre de" en parlant de manifestation, d'événement, de sommet, rencontre, conférence par ex.

Comment: @XouDo Ces sontd es situation que j'avais eu dans la tête aussi: *une réunion en marge de conférence* ou *une manifestation en marge de sommet* sont lié aux ces conferénce et sommet... jusqu'au point qu'on peut les considerer comme des parties de la conferénce / le sommet.